# How to check YARN mapreduce tasks max heap size setting

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am facing a problem where my M/R job tasks fail with heap space errors, while job configuration lists 2 properties that should affect that:

```
mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx200m
mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx2048m
```

The first one is legacy configuration that ended up in job.xml who knows how, and the second one is my job configuration. I was using oozie to submit the job and it somehow put these two configurations in...

Is there a way to check which of these two configurations were actually used for java opts for my map task? Is there a log perhaps or a way to profile the jvm in order to see it? I need to know this to rule out a possibility of bug in my code causing heap space error.

Answer (score 0):

there should be a job_xxx.conf.xml file in mapreduce history servers directory on hdfs when the job completes.  otherwise you can find this file in the users hdfs directory under /user//.staging/jobid/ during runtime